# How do I run embedded Excel, from Word, in the debugger

Tags: excel, ms-word, office-addins, excel-addins

I start the Visual Studio debugger, to debug my AddIn, where I tell the debugger to launch Word and it runs fine. Breakpoints hit, etc.

My AddIn runs under Word, Excel, & PowerPoint. Same DLL runs with all three. THis is an IDTExtensibility2 AddIn, not VSTO.

I then embed an Excel Worksheet in my Word document and when I am editing or opening that, my AddIn is running. But it is not under the debugger.

How can I get my AddIn attached to the embedded Excel to run under my debugger?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this page? (Add-in Debug and Testing). I was able to open a `Safari` console on my Mac. Don't know what you have. Make sure you are developing on office version 16+.